# Matlab - data import with fixed numbers of columns

Tags: matlab, csv, import

I have a (maybe simple) question about Matlab data import. I want to import a huge dataset (~1GB) which has a comma separated format like this:

```
 08:05, 12, 33, 124, 13, 08:06, 22, 84, 12, 35, ..
```

Every 5th value is a timestamp. I want to import it with a fixed numbers of colums (5 colums), but there is no delimiter for the end of row. It should look like this in the end:

```
08:05  12  33  124  13
08:06  22  14  1    35
08:07  22  124 12   34
08:08  22  12  12   0
```

I thought about replacing every 5th comma by a subroutine, but it's too time consuming. Do you know a better solution? I'm hoping for a nice build-in function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fscanf` and C-type format strings to accomplish this. For example:

```
fid=fopen('filename.txt');
A=reshape(fscanf(fid,'%d:%d, %d, %d, %d, %d, '),6,[])';
fclose(fid);
```

This stores your answer in a matrix A which will contain

```
A =
     8     5    12    33   124    13
     8     6    22    84    12    35
```

If you want to format this into a string or output file as you listed, you could use:

```
fprintf('%02d:%02d  %-3d %-3d %-3d %-3d\n',A')
```

Comment: @user2037819, If that's what you needed, consider upvoting and accepting the answer so people know your issue was solved.